# Keylogger in raspy?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any way I could use my Raspberry Pi as a keylogger of a PC? Like getting the input of the PC's keyboard to a raspy plugged to the computer via usb.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you could install a keylogger program on the PC and have it send keystrokes to the Raspberry Pi ... otherwise, it is difficult to intercept data on a cable that is plugged into a PC

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could plug in keyboard into Pi and simulate a keyboard to the upstream connected PC and pass all pressed keys upstream. Then you would get a hardware based pi key logger, a bit bold and complicated but it should be possible.